# Pandas, scikit - split train and test with condition

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a dataframe, data, with the following structure (mine is actually much bigger, but this is just for illustration purposes):

```
a b c tag
A 3 2 4
B 2 1 3
A 5 3 3
A 4 3 2
B 2 4 3
A 3 5 2
B 4 1 1
C 2 3 1
C 1 3 4
B 5 2 4
```

I'm using scikit-learn to split the data:

`train, test = train_test_split(data, test_size=test_size)`

However, I want to find a way to split the data in a way that guarantees that I have at least one row of each tag in both sets. For the example dataset, that would mean having something like this (but shuffled, of course):

train

`a b c tag
A 3 2 4
B 2 1 3
A 4 3 2 
B 4 1 1`

test
`similar but with the remaining elements (according to the proportion)`

Basically I would like to have the entire range/variety of tags in both sets.

I appreciate in advance all the help.

`

Comment: check the parameter `stratify =` inside the function

Answer (score -1):

I think this is what yo u are after.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
```

See the link below for more info on this topic.

https://towardsdatascience.com/train-test-split-and-cross-validation-in-python-80b61beca4b6

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to "guarantees that I have at least one row of each tag in both sets" as the OP asked.